# what's the different about: Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync vs OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

after execute these code below, the result is the seam:

```
OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({forMSGraphAccess: true}).then( function(result) {console.log(result);});
```

and

```
Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync(function(result) {
    if (result.status === "succeeded") {
        console.log(result.value)
    } else {
        console.log("Error obtaining token", result.error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@hello_chenchen both APIs are same. OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken is the newer version and uses promise instead of callback. You can check the documentation for [OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-runtime/officeruntime.auth?view=excel-js-preview#getAccessToken_options_)
and [Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.auth?view=excel-js-preview#getAccessTokenAsync_callback_) to see the difference between return type and arguments.

Comment: The getAccessTokenAsync supposedly fails for office.com and gmail is says in the doc (although for me at least, office.com seems to work anyhow).